Issue of readdir() reading the pointer to a directory
The basic logic in this problem is that the program scans over a directory for N times, and does some operation on specific file inside.
The bug comes out as: program employs rewinddir() to put the pointer back to the beginning of directory. However, for the 2nd out of N runs, the readdir() cannot read this pointer anymore, but return (nil).
I editted the question with the update of MRE. This is the whole code which can be applied on a directory immediately. I'm sorry if it's long. I've already deleted lots unused part of it. The directory path is /home/yjiang46/k2_k4/k2=0.80/configs/, and there are thousands of files named in form l4000k80000_h0_all_*****-shelling, where ***** goes from 100 to 500000, in the step of quantity of around hundreds. Sorry I cannot upload the whole directory here, which is too big.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <math.h>

int sample[60];
double average[1000]; // Assume the max layer of a shelling function is 1000
char shelling[1000][1000];//read all the data in shelling 2D matrix
int file_num = 0;
int *name_index;
int N = 0;
int B = 100;

void swap(int* x1, int* x2) {
    int temp;
    temp = *x1;
    *x1 = *x2;
    *x2 = temp;
}

int partition(int *name_index, int low, int high) {
    int i;
    i = low - 1;
    int j;
    for (j = low; j <= high; j++)
        if (name_index[j] < name_index[high]) {
            i++;
            swap(&name_index[i], &name_index[j]);
        }
    swap(&name_index[i + 1], &name_index[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void QuickSort(int *name_index, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pi;
        pi = partition(name_index, low, high);

        QuickSort(name_index, low, pi - 1);
        QuickSort(name_index, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void extract_convert_name(char filename[]) {
    char name_list[8];
    int i = 0;
    while (!(filename[i] == 'a' && filename[i + 1] == 'l' && filename[i + 2] == 'l'))
        i++;
    int j;
    for (j = i + 4; filename[j] >= '0' && filename[j] <= '9'; j++)
        name_list[j - i - 4] = filename[j];
    name_index[N] = atoi(name_list);
    N++;
    memset(name_list, '\0', sizeof(name_list));
}

void name_blocking(int *name_index, int *b_name_index) {
    //average part
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    for (i = 0; i < (N / B); i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < B; k++) 
            b_name_index[i] += name_index[i * B + k];
        b_name_index[i] = b_name_index[i] / (double)B;
    }
}

int main() {

    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* in_file;
    FILE* fp;
    char filename[1000];
    memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
    char* directory_name;
  
    if ((directory_name = (char *)malloc((size_t)50)) != NULL)
        getcwd(directory_name, (size_t)200);
    strcat(directory_name, "/configs/"); 

    
    dir = opendir(directory_name);

    int layer_number = 0;

    memset(shelling, '\0', sizeof(shelling[0][0])*1000000);

    int j;
    char head[1000];
    head[0]='\0';
    strcat(head,"l4000k80000");
    int head_len;
    head_len = strlen(head);
    char str2[] = "shelling";
    int str_len;
    char *filepath = directory_name;
    int dir_len = strlen(directory_name);

    while (in_file = readdir(dir)) { // count the number of files in a directory
        if (strncmp(in_file->d_name, head, head_len) == 0)
            file_num++;
    }
    printf("\n file_num is ** %d **\n", file_num);

    double **jk = calloc(file_num, sizeof(double*));
    if (jk == NULL)
        printf("\n************\n************\n\n There is no space for jk[]!\n\n************\n************\n");
    for (j = 0; j < file_num; j++)
        jk[j] = calloc(1000, sizeof(double));


    name_index = calloc(file_num, sizeof(int));
    if (name_index == NULL)
        printf("\n************\n************\n\n There is no space for name_index[]!\n\n************\n************\n");
  
    int *b_name_index;
    b_name_index = calloc(file_num/B, sizeof(int));
    if (b_name_index == NULL)
        printf("\n************\n************\n\n There is no space for b_name_index[]!\n\n************\n************\n");

    rewinddir(dir);
    while (in_file = readdir(dir)) { // read the whole directory into shelling[][]
        strcat(filename, in_file->d_name);
        str_len = strlen(filename);
        char* pointer = &filename[str_len - 8];
        if (strncmp(filename, head, head_len) == 0 && strcmp(pointer, str2) == 0) //compare head with k2 and tail with "shelling"
            extract_convert_name(filename);
        //printf("%s\n", filename);
        memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
    }

    QuickSort(name_index, 0, N - 1);
    printf("\n N is ** %d **\n", N);
 
    name_blocking(name_index, b_name_index);
  
    int n;
    strcat(head, "_h0_all_"); //char head[] = "l4000k80000";
  
    head_len = strlen(head);
    char tail[] = "-shelling";
    char int_to_str_index[10];
    for (n = 0; n < N;) {
    
        rewinddir(dir);
        printf("just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = %p\n", dir);
        sprintf(int_to_str_index, "%d", name_index[n]);
        strcat(head, int_to_str_index);
        strcat(head, tail);
        //printf("head: %s\n", head);
        if (n == 1)
            printf("(n=1) directory pointer: %p, pointer dir: %p\n", readdir(dir), dir);
        while (in_file = readdir(dir)) {// read the whole directory into shelling[][]
            printf("directory pointer: %p, pointer dir: %p\n", readdir(dir), dir);
            filename[0] = '\0';//empty a string

            strcat(filename, in_file->d_name);
            //printf("filename: %s\n", filename);
            if (strcmp(filename, head) == 0) {//compare head with k2 and tail with "shelling"
                strcat(filepath, filename);
                //operations inserted here
                filepath[dir_len] = '\0';
                head[head_len] = '\0';
                n++;
                break;      
            }
        }  //next search
    }

    return 0;
}

And I used if (n == 1) just because without it i cannot get any information from 2nd run.
The output is:
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e328, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e378, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e3e0, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e440, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e4a0, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e508, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e568, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
(thousands of printed lines following...)
directory pointer: 0x55687997e340, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e3a8, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
directory pointer: 0x55687997e418, pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
just after rewinddir(dir): pointer = 0x55687997e2e0
(n=1) directory pointer: (nil), pointer dir: 0x55687997e2e0
(thousands of printed lines following until exited forcedly bc of dead loop)

So actually, it is easy to tell, in the second run, the pointer dir is already put back to 0x55687997e2e0, the beginning of the directory, but the readdir() just won't read it.
I run this program on CONDOR, but also tesitify it locally on my terminal, and the outputs are the same.
I posted this question a week before, and it was deleted by me because of the lack of MCVE or MRE. I have updated all the requisite for this question. Thank you all for helping.

There's no need for memset(shelling, '\0', sizeof(shelling[0][0])*1000000);. Global variables are zeroed by default. You can also simplify the third argument to just sizeof(shelling).

getcwd(directory_name, (size_t)200); You only allocated 50 bytes for directory_name, why do you use 200 here? Why are you using malloc() at all, why not just char directory_name[200];?

What happens if you don't call QuickSort?

rewinddir() doesn't change the value of dir. It updates internal state that the pointer points to.

@Barmar thank you. I just relocated from 50 to 200, and it works out
